# instantiating datepicker on dynamically created input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to duplicate a field with a datepicker. The field gets duplicated, but the datepicker only shows on the first two fields... I've tried other workarounds such as adding a `live` listener to the field that calls the datepicker, but no go.

```
var dc=0;
jQuery('#otherRecAdd').click(function(){
    dc++;
    var d=$('othrRecDates').innerHTML;
    var nd=document.createElement('div');
    nd.innerHTML=d;
    var divID='othrDate'+dc;
    nd.id=divID;
    jq(nd).attr('id','orInID'+dc);
    var ind=jq(nd).find('input');
    var indID='orDate'+dc;
    jq(ind).attr('id',indID)
    document.getElementById('otherReccuranceDiv').appendChild(nd);
    var x=jq("input[name=othrRdate]");//x.length increments correctly; it is finding all of the inputs
    x.datepicker();
})

//this doesn't work either
jq(function(){
    jq('input[name=othrRdate]').live('click', function() {
        jq(this).datepicker({showOn:'focus'}).focus();
    });
});
```

So the form starts out with one input and the datepicker works correctly. If I duplicate that input, the duplicated input works correctly. However, after this, any subsequently duplicated inputs do not work as expected. Here is the generated html:

```
<label for="otherRec">Other Reccurance</label></b>
<input name="otherRec" id="otherRec" onclick='toggleDiv("othrRecDates");' type="checkbox">
<div id="othrRecDates" style="">
    <b>Date:</b>
    <input class="hasDatepicker" name="othrRdate" id="date" type="text">
    <br>
</div>
<div id="orInID1">
    <b>Date:</b>
    <input class="hasDatepicker" name="othrRdate" id="orDate1" type="text">
    <br>
</div>
<div id="orInID2">
    <b>Date:</b>
    <input class="hasDatepicker" name="othrRdate" id="orDate2" type="text">
    <br>
</div>
<div id="orInID3">
    <b>Date:</b>
    <input class="hasDatepicker" name="othrRdate" id="orDate3" type="text">
    <br>
</div>
```

And I just realized that this won't work for me either as the `name` attributes need to be unique. I suppose better solution would be something akin to the above but with className selection instead of name.

Any ideas would be awesomely awesomed.

edit: yes, I am mixing prototype and jQuery :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this a bit simpler entirely in jQuery, for example:

```
var dc=0;
jQuery('#otherRecAdd').click(function() {
    dc++;
    jQuery('#othrRecDates')           //get id="othrRecDates" as a jQuery object
      .clone()                        //make a copy
      .attr('id', 'othrDate'+dc)      //give it a new id
      .show()                         //show it, assuming the template is hidden
      .appendTo('#otherReccuranceDiv')//append it where it does in the DOM
      .find('input')                  //get the child <input>
      .attr('id', 'orDate'+dc)        //set it's ID, possible name here too
      .datepicker();                  //create a datepicker on it
});
```

This just creates the [`.datepicker()`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) on your new `<input>` as it's created.  [You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/5Dm7f/1/).  The above is broken out for explanation, but it can be condensed down as much as is readable, like this:

```
var dc=0;
jQuery('#otherRecAdd').click(function() {
    dc++;
    jQuery('#othrRecDates').clone().attr('id', 'othrDate'+dc).show()
      .appendTo('#otherReccuranceDiv')
      .find('input').attr('id', 'orDate'+dc).datepicker();
});
```

Answer (score 5):

It drove me nuts the other day! Looks like the jqueryui datepicker ignores the elements with class "hasDatepicker". Assigning a new unique id and removing the hasDatepicker class did the magic.

```
if($(objParentTR).next().find('input')){ //spot the input field and iterate
  $(objParentTR).next().find('input').each(function(i, domEle){
  if($(domEle).hasClass("clsDatePicker")){
    $(domEle).attr('id', 'dyncal'+tID++).removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker();                         
   }
});
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this, that was exactly my issue. Adjusting my code to say $(this).removeClass("hasDatepicker").datepicker().focus(); fixed my issue.